# How can I keep only the rows with the smallest KEY value based on columns in Arrow data type?

Tags: r

How can I keep only the rows with the smallest KEY value based on policy number, date of birth, and status?
**I'm wondering how to do it in arrow format instead of dataframe format** because the data is very large and dataframing it would take too much time.

```
data <- data.frame(policynumber = c(10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 6),
                   status = c("RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_DTH", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NEW", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN"),
                   birthdate = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1991, 1991, 1990),
                   add = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   KEY = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1))

data <- arrow::as_arrow_table(data) %>% filter(KEY %in% c(1, 2))

# If I use the dataframe
data %>% group_by(policynumber, status, birthdate) %>% filter(key == min(KEY))

# Arrow data type (Please answer me)
data %>% ......
```

Comment: You don't need to convert an arrow datset to a dataframe to do some analysis (if that was the question): https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/arrow.html#analyzing-arrow-data-with-dplyr

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't just want to leave specific columns, I want to leave all the columns, so it's an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`arrow` does not currently support grouped window functions, so `group_by(..) %>% filter(key == min(key))` cannot work. It's a limitation that I hope they are looking to remedy

In the interim you can summarize and inner-join (while still in "lazy" mode):

```r
data <- data.frame(policynumber = c(10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 6),
                   status = c("RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_DTH", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NEW", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN", "RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN"),
                   birthdate = c(1992, 1992, 1992, 1991, 1991, 1990),
                   add = c(2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   KEY = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), EMPTY1=1:6, EMPTY2=11:16) %>%
  arrow::as_arrow_table()

data %>%
  group_by(policynumber, status, birthdate) %>%
  summarize(KEY = min(KEY)) %>%
  inner_join(data, by = c("policynumber", "status", "birthdate", "KEY")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 5 × 7
#   policynumber status                   birthdate   KEY   add EMPTY1 EMPTY2
#          <dbl> <chr>                        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
# 1           10 RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_DTH      1992     1     2      1     11
# 2           10 RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN      1992     1     2      2     12
# 3            5 RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NEW      1991     1     4      4     14
# 4            5 RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN      1991     1     5      5     15
# 5            6 RMA_TRANSACTION_TYPE_REN      1990     1     6      6     16
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i want to leave only specific columns then your answer would be helpful. But there are 92 columns in the actual data I have, and there are only 2 columns I want to group when I find a case where the KEY value is the minimum value. 
In this case, when I use the inner_join, even the overlapping information will join, so I don't think the desired result will come out. Is there any other way?

Comment: The notion of `inner_join(data, ...)` ensures that _all_ columns in `data` are returned. I just added two extra columns for fun, ran the unchanged code, and the added columns are still there. Please test the code on your real data, ensure you get all of the columns you expect, and then comment how it doesn't work for you. (If something about it works here but not with your real data,  it would be really helpful to add a corner-case in the sample data that triggers a failure.)

Comment: Said differently, I don't understand your issue that "overlapping information will join". If there are rows that should not be returned, or rows that are not returned that should be, then we'll need to revisit the sample data and conditions required to select rows.